# PySpark Py4JJavaError from Data Frame Built reading files whose names change during job run

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, etl, amazon-emr

I am getting the following exception while running a PySpark script in EMR:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o103.parquet.
```

This error occurs because the data frame that I am building is based off of multiple `.parquet` files, and the names of those files are changing while the job is running. I believe this because in the error logs there is something like

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory 's3://filename.parquet'
```

The things that I have tried are

1. Catch the `Py4JJavaError` exception and re-create the dataframe object
2. Eagerly cache the data frame immediately after creation using something like

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
spark.sql("CACHE TABLE df")
```

Suggestions on how I can build a dataframe around files whose names are changing would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Spark can read multiple files at once, no issue. What do you mean "changing"? As in files are rewritten? If so, then seems like you should fix that process so files aren't being removed while you are reading them (S3 files aren't updated in place)

Comment: There is a separate process that may be running at the same time as my Spark job, that will overwrite the files in S3 that the Spark job is reading to create a data frame.

Comment: @OneCricketeer could you elaborate on what you mean by "S3 files aren't updated in place"?

Comment: Meaning you cannot append to an existing file, to my knowledge. Spark is overwriting whole files. So, it will delete and then write a new one. Thus, you get "FileNotFoundException" when trying to read at the same time